# Rails 3 and scheduling of repetitive tasks without cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, queue, scheduling, task, repeat

I have a app and i am currently using delayed_job. I was wondering if there are any recommended gems that do scheduling of repetitive tasks.

I want to schedule task that happen on a certain frequency to clean the database/sending emails/run other methods.
I mite want to run some tasks every day or every hour.

Is there any good ones out there that are fairly easy to setup and config which do not use CRON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert that repetitive work to rakes and call those rakes via cron.
For setting cron over server, whenever is nice gem
checkout here - http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

Comment: i was asking for ones that do not use cron.

Comment: @Jordan. I have used the Whenever gem with cron and was interested in using one that does not rely on cron. I do have delayed_job running in my app and its fine for delaying tasks to a later date but i would like something similar that i can place tasks on a schedule that the app constantly checks and executes how cron does.

Comment: delayed job delays tasks, so user experience can be improved, he shouldn't be tied if same thing can be done in background. you can't use this for scheduling things you see.

Answer (score 1):

there are some very good gems about schedule repetitive tasks
i tried [delayed job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) it is simple and easy to use you can watch  [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job) to details of using it

Answer (score 0):

You can try rufus-scheduler https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler It is an app based scheduler (unless you use it's cron feature).